# use php die / exit to block html from execute?

Tags: php

it seem `die()` and `exit()` only block to run the below php but not html.

How to use php if else statement to display html? I do not prefer echo because I would like to prevent the user to see my entire code (from `<body`>to`</body>`)

Comment: Please post the code you have and explain what you want to do.  Anything sent by `echo` _will_ be visible to the client browser.

Answer (score 3):

[`die()`](http://php.net/die) or [`exit()`](http://php.net/exit) **stops** all scripts, even html output, *when file is executed by php*:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
?>

<html>

<?php exit(); ?>

</html>
```

Output:

```
<html>
```

---

Another alternative is to use [`return`](http://php.net/return) to stop general script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
?>

<html>

<?php return; ?>

</html>
```

But it stops only current script.

---

Yes, you may use conditional statement to control output like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$showbody = false;
?>

<html>

<?php if($showbody): ?>
    <body>
        Here is the body!
    </body>
<?php endif; ?>

</html>
```

Output:

```
<html>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(false){
   die();
}else{ php?>
  <body>

  </body>
<?php }?>
```

This is quite ugly, but I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: i want to protect my login page.. isset is not enough.. is ur code for that? or there is a better way?

Comment: Well it depends on what are you protecting exactly, but my code will simply prevent html to be showed to the users if condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [Output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions of PHP.

Basically if you don't have output buffering enabled whenever something is echo'd, printed or html is included it immediately starts getting sent to the client. With output buffering enabled it will all get stored and you can control when or even if it get's sent.